# CSS media query nota recognized with :before element

Tags: css

This Code isnt working and I dont understand what is happening, since everything else is working fine and I have the meta viewport tag on the header:

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.content:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .content:before {
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
  }
}
```

I tried to modify the media with screen and min-width. I also tried to swap the medias position and nothings showing on Google chromes dev console, while other medias and rules are showing and working properly.

Is it posible to modify those attributes on that kind of element with CSS?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it is "not recognized"?  Does it simply fail to apply?  Can you share a [mcve] with some markup so we can recreate and better understand this issue?

Comment: I can't help reading the rest of the question in a Mexican accent after reading the typo in the heading!

Comment: Could the missing semicolon be affecting the CSS below it?

Comment: Your code is working fine. The only thing I'm not clear on is whether you want the pseudo element to be positioned relative to the .content element (in which case you need to give that a position: relative for example) or whether you want it to position in relation to some other ancestor (possibly all the way back up to body).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the unit in your media query:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .content:before {
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed. Please accept and upvote the answer if it solved the issue :)